# why cant I draw triangle on the Qt Widget

Tags: c++, qt, opengl

Well, these days I am trying to use OpenGL libs on Qt 5.1.1. I add a Widget in the mainwindow.ui, and then promote it to class,

Here is the class' head file,

```
#ifndef GLWIDGET_H
#define GLWIDGET_H

#include <QGLWidget>

#include <core.hpp>
#include <cv.hpp>

#include <GL/glut.h>

class GLWidget : public QGLWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit GLWidget(QWidget *parent = 0);

    void initializeGL();
    void paintGL();
    void resizeGL(int w, int h);

signals:

public slots:

private:

};

#endif // GLWIDGET_H
```

and here is the class' cpp file

```
#include "glwidget.h"

GLWidget::GLWidget(QWidget *parent) :
    QGLWidget(parent)
{
}

void GLWidget::initializeGL()
{
    glClearColor((GLclampf)0, (GLclampf)0, \
                 (GLclampf)1, (GLclampf)1);
}

void GLWidget::paintGL()
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    glColor3f(1.0, 0, 0);
    glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
        glVertex3f(-0.5, -0.5, 0);
        glVertex3f(0.5, -0.5, 0);
        glVertex3f(0.0, -0.5, 0);
    glEnd();
}

void GLWidget::resizeGL(int w, int h)
{

}
```

but the codes in `paintGL()` dont seem to work, I only can change the background's color by changing the code in `initializeGL()`;

the project's output is as follow,

[image]

update: I am sorry, I forgot show the `.pro`  file

```
#-------------------------------------------------
#
# Project created by QtCreator 2016-04-27T13:28:29
#
#-------------------------------------------------

QT       += core gui opengl

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

TARGET = gradDesign
TEMPLATE = app


SOURCES += main.cpp\
        mainwindow.cpp \
        showimage.cpp \
        glwidget.cpp

HEADERS  += mainwindow.h \
    showimage.h \
    glwidget.h

FORMS    += mainwindow.ui \
    showimage.ui

INCLUDEPATH +=F:\\opencv30\\build\\include \
    F:\\opencv30\\build\\include\opencv \
    F:\\opencv30\build\\include\\opencv2 \
    F:\\freeglut\\include

CONFIG +=debug_and_release

CONFIG(debug, debug|release)
{
    LIBS +=F:\\opencv30\\build\\x86\\vc12\\lib\\opencv_ts300d.lib \
        F:\\opencv30\\build\\x86\\vc12\\lib\\opencv_world300d.lib \
        F:\\freeglut\\build\\lib\\freeglutd.lib \
        F:\\freeglut\\build\\lib\\freeglut_staticd.lib
}

CONFIG(release, debug|release)
{
    LIBS +=F:\\opencv30\\build\\x86\\vc12\\lib\\opencv_ts300.lib \
        F:\\opencv30\\build\\x86\\vc12\\lib\\opencv_world300.lib \
        F:\\freeglut\\build\\lib\\freeglut.lib \
        F:\\freeglut\\build\\lib\\freeglut_static.lib
}

RC_ICONS = uestc.ico
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You didn't setup any camera matrix, so you don't know where your virtual camera is located and if the triangle is visible.
You can start with an orthographic camera:

```
void GLWidget::resizeGL(int width, int height)
{
    // ...
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();

    glOrtho(-2, +2, -2, +2, -1.0, 1.0);

    // ...
}
```

In addition you are trying to draw a degenerate triangle (all the y are the same). Try with:

```
glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
    glVertex3f(-0.5, -0.5, 0);
    glVertex3f(0.5, -0.5, 0);
    glVertex3f(0.0, 0.0, 0);
glEnd();
```